# Reset Migrations from Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to reset Entity Framework migrations as if I had never used this functionality.

I tried to :

1. Delete Migrations folder
2. Delete table "dbo._EFMigrationsHistory"
3. Then type: `Add-Migration Initial`

The result is :

```
namespace fretapp.Migrations
{
    public partial class Test : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I deleted all the tables from my database, but the models in API are still here, so It should update the database, but no code here.

Then I tried to :

1. Delete Migrations folder
2. DROP database
3. Create a new database with a new name
4. Change connexion string in the database context
5. I got exactly the same result...

So where are the data from migrations stored???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild?

Comment: I didn't rebuild indeed. So you think it's because I should run the app to take account the clean migration folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can undo all the migration by using the below command.

```
Update-Database -Target:0
```

Or you run the below command

```
Update-Database <First MigrationName>
```

so all the migration will be undone, then you can make the changes and generate the new migration and proceed with the work.